# 0-1 integer linear programming approximation algorithms

Tags: binary, integer, linear-programming, approximation

Hi I am looking for an approximation algorithm for 0-1 integer linear programming. Currently the approximation algorithms I find need to relax the interval to be [0,1]. However, my problem can only treat 0 or 1 as the solution.

Does anyone have ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic procedure to obtain an integral solution would be branch-and-bound. If this is not what you are looking fore, provide more details.

Comment: Hi Chris, the branch-and-bound is right for me. I examined an [example of branch-and-bound](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/1159/1186960/cdrom_modules/module_c.pdf). The time complexity of 0-1 case seems to be exponential. Am I right? Do you know some approximation algorithms with smaller time complexity?

Comment: that is true for the worst case. But the performance of branch and bound depends on several aspects, for example the branching rules or if the primal and dual bounds are good. These influence, how large the search tree becomes.

Comment: you can relax your 0/1 constraint and get solution(fractional values) of relaxed LP. Then you can find a threshold to round of the fractional values to 1 or 0, and threshold must be chosen such that all constraints still satisfy. Now, you can analyse the approximation ratio you obtained. I can provide an example If this is what you were looking for.